# do's and don'ts of __init__ method

Tags: python, function, class, initialization, init

I was just wondering if it's considered wildly inappropriate, just messy, or unconventional at all to use the **init** method to set variables by calling, one after another, the rest of the functions within a class. I have done things like, self.age = ch_age(), where ch_age is a function within the same class, and set more variables the same way, like self.name=ch_name() etc. Also, what about prompting for user input within **init** specifically to get the arguments with which to call ch_age? The latter feels a little wrong I must say. Any advice, suggestions, admonishments welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always favor being lazy: if you NEED to initialize everything in the constructor, you should--in a lot of cases, I put a general "reset" method in my class. Then you can call that method in init, and can re-initialize the class instance easily.

But if you don't need those variables initially, I feel it's better to wait to initialize things until you actually need them.

For your specific case

```
class Blah1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name=self.ch_name()
    def ch_name(self):
        return 'Ozzy'
```

you might as well use the property decorator. The following will have the same effect:

```
class Blah2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @property
    def name():
        return 'Ozzy'
```

In both of the implementations above, the following code should not issue any exceptions:

```
>>> b1 = Blah1()
>>> b2 = Blah2()
>>> assert b1.name == 'Ozzy'
>>> assert b2.name == 'Ozzy'
```

If you wanted to provide a reset method, it might look something like this:

```
class Blah3(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.reset(name)
    def reset(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

Comment: +1 since a reset method is basically something you can call at any time for an instance of a object even after calling the constructor. reset methods are very useful for classes that you implement as iterators since sometimes you want to reset the position of an iterator (for example a spritesheet class in a game that loops through several small images). There are probably a lot of other uses for a reset method as well for different types of objects.

Comment: so it appears the property decorator is using the name of the function, in this case "name" and creating an attribute with this name, and a value equal to the returned value?

Comment: Yeah...it's pretty handy.

Comment: what about a case where your method returns two objects, like a string and a list? Can the property decorator deal with this?

Comment: I don't see why not..you're just returning a tuple.